# Procedure or function 'usp_ClientHistoryItem' expects parameter '@iReturnTripRef', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, .net, database, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am providing 0 for column with type in tin Database but it returns with exception

> Procedure or function 'usp_ClientHistoryItem' expects parameter
>   '@iTripRef', which was not supplied.

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_ClientHistoryItem", conn))
 {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      SqlParameter parameterID = new SqlParameter("@ID", oReservation.Id);
      parameterID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterID); 

      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhoneNo", oReservation.ClientPhone));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", oReservation.UserID));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iTripRef", 0));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", oReservation.TestId));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", oReservation.StartDate));

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value);

      return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iTripRef", 0);
```

instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iTripRef", 0));
```